# iPhone compass broken?

Tags: iphone, magnetometer

I've written a small application for using the iPhone's 3GS-and-better magnet.
It is loosely based on Apple's Teslameter sample code.

What I've noticed is that on some iPhone devices it works.
On others, there's a first exceptional reading - and then, no more readings.

What's common to those problematic devices is that they were exposed to magnets longer that your average iPhone...

So, I'm wondering if (1) could this have "broken" the iPhone compass? (2) if yes, is there anyway to fix it? (3) is there any way to "reset" via software?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity: How and why were the problematic devices exposed to magnets?

Comment: Science teachers (the app is supposed to help experiment with magnets during science class)

Comment: Unbelievable... I simply added 
-(BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration : (CLLocationManager *)manager {
    //do stuff
    return YES;
}
and things started working...